# Examples in which it is very difficult to find a $\delta$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I'm reading Henle/Kleinenberg's *Infinitesimal Calculus*. They say on page $8$:

> [image]

Can you provide examples in which it is very difficult to find a $\delta$? The example they provided in the previous page is very elementar, I'd like to see how hard it could be.

Comment: What's the example that you found elementary? I myself have never read the book so I have no idea what should be the appropriate answer to this question.

Comment: @BigbearZzz The example is $f(x)=x^2$. But whatever you find hard, just bring it on.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind is the Riemann-Zeta function $\zeta(s)$:

$$ \zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-s} = 1 + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{3^s}+\dots, \quad s > 1$$
without using any identitites, this sure looks complicated to me. I guess you could easily come up with other examples of function series that are difficult to handle.